# Manipulating Python Magic Methods

Tags: python, class, methods

I have more of a background with data science libraries or calling methods and attributes from classes. I am experimenting with manipulating magic methods. I am having a difficult time getting `bool` types and returning their opposites.

I did something with `str` and `datetime` objects that worked but can't seem to to the same with `__cmp__`, `__lt__`, `__eq__` or `**gt**'. Here is my code:

```
class Opposite:

    def __cmp__(self, other):

        if other.__class__.__name__ == 'bool':
            return other

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if other.__class__.__name__ == 'bool':
            return other

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if other.__class__.__name__ == 'bool':
            return other

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if other.__class__.__name__ == 'bool':
            return other


if __name__=="__main__":

    """ test class Compare """

    a = 1
    b = 1
    c = a < b
    d = a > b
    e = a == b

print("Results:\na\t{}\nb\t{}\nc\t{}\nd\t{}\ne\t{}\n".format(a,b,c,d,e))
print("\nType:\na-type\t{}\nb-type\t{}\nc-type\t{}\nd-type\t{}\ne-type\t{}\n"
      .format(type(a),type(b),type(c),type(d),type(e)))
```

This prints the following:

```
Results:
a   1
b   1
c   False
d   False
e   True

Type:
a-type  <class 'int'>
b-type  <class 'int'>
c-type  <class 'bool'>
d-type  <class 'bool'>
e-type  <class 'bool'>
```

As you can see, the results are the same as not using the class at all. I added an `__init__` method to print `using Opposite` and it only prints that if I instantiate the object with something like `a = Opposite()`.

I would like to enter something like `a > b`, `a < b`, or `a == b`, and return the opposite boolean value, `True`, or `False`, as an exercise.

I tried several things such as placing the methods under the `__init__` method I created, which didn't work either. I read on this and still don't quite understand how to do this with booleans, integers and floats for that matter. The way the methods are above is how I was able to turn datetime objects into strings with `__add__`, `__radd__` and `__rsub__` methods.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**

Thanks to your help, I have a better understanding and have completed my small experiment with this code:

```
class Opposite:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return not self._x < other._x

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return not self._x == other._x

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return not self._x > other._x

    def __le__(self, other):
        return not self._x <= other._x

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return not self._x >= other._x

def tester(w, x, y, z):
    try:
        # Original values
        a = w < x
        b = w > x
        c = w == x
        d = w <= x
        e = w >= x

        # Opposite values
        f = y < z
        g = y > z
        h = y == z
        i = y <= z
        j = y >= z

        # Results
        k = 'Fail' if a == f else 'Success'
        l = 'Fail' if b == g else 'Success'
        m = 'Fail' if c == h else 'Success'
        n = 'Fail' if d == i else 'Success'
        o = 'Fail' if e == j else 'Success'

        print('\nComparing {} and {}:\t<\t>\t==\t<=\t>='.format(w, x))
        print('Original Values:', end='\t')
        print('{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}'.format(a, b, c, d, e))
        print('Opposite Values:', end='\t')
        print('{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}'.format(f, g, h, i, j))
        print('Comparisons:', end='\t')
        print('\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}'.format(k, l, m, n, o))

    except(Exception) as err:
        print(err)

if __name__=="__main__":

    """ test class Compare """

    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = Opposite(a)
    d = Opposite(b)
    tester(a, b, c, d)
```

This prints the following:

```
Comparing 1 and 2:  <   >   ==  <=  >=
Original Values:    True    False   False   True    False
Opposite Values:    False   True    True    False   True
Comparisons:        Success Success Success Success Success
```

Comment: You didn't make any instances of your class at all. Why do you expect your comparison code to execute? You'd need to make instances of `Opposite` for your code to be used (and to be clear, as written it's not the opposite of anything). Also, if this is Python 3, `__cmp__` isn't magic anymore, only the individual rich comparison methods are used.

Comment: For your class methods to be used the left operand has to be an instance of that class. Yours is an `int`.

Comment: @KlausD.: Technically, it can work if the right operand is an instance of the class, and the left operand has a correctly implemented comparator (one that returns `NotImplemented` when it doesn't know how to compare itself to the right operand); in that case, the left operand is tried, and when it returns `NotImplemented`, [the reflected operand is tried for the right hand side](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) (see final paragraph of linked section). Of course, in the OP's case, nothing is an instance of the class at all.

Comment: That is correct, but does not apply to his class and an int.

Comment: Originally, I was hoping to manipulate say `__lt__` so I can simply perform `2 < 1` and get `True` without instantiating the class, but that isn't how it works. I would have to break python to do that lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you want to return the negation of the boolean resulting from the comparison you could do something like

```
class T:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return not self._x < other._x

t1 = T(1)
t2 = T(2)

print(t1 < t2) #False
```

Note that in the comparison `self._x < other._x` you are using the `__lt__` method of the int class.